# How to pass table name as a parameter to cursor with out creating view in a dynamic way

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to delete the records with the break-even commits.

I am passing the table name, date and cleanup frequency as the parameters to the procedure. As we need to have break-even commits, I am using the cursor however cursor is not allowing to take the table name as a parameter.

Can I have leads if any below is the code that I developed?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_datacleanup_test`(IN tab_name VARCHAR(50),
                            IN modified_date VARCHAR(20),
                            IN cleanup_window VARCHAR(30),
                            OUT recordsProcessed INT)
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE No_More_Rows INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
    DECLARE modified_dt varchar(50);
    DECLARE v_counter INT;
    DECLARE stmt varchar (500);
    DECLARE rowsdeleted INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
    

    BEGIN
    DECLARE Sel_cur CURSOR for select cast(modified_dateas char) as modified_dt,count(1) as counter from tab_name where status_flag = 'D' and modified_date <= cleanup_window group by modified_date; 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET No_More_Rows = TRUE;


        OPEN Sel_cur;
        READ_LOOP:LOOP
        
            FETCH Sel_cur INTO modified_dt,v_counter;
        
                IF No_More_Rows THEN
                    LEAVE READ_LOOP;
                END IF;

                SELECT modified_dt,v_counter;
            
                set @delstm = concat('delete from ', tab_name,' where ', modified_date,' = ''',modified_dt,''' 
                            and status_flag = ''D''');
            
                PREPARE stmt FROM @delstm; 
                EXECUTE stmt; 
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        
                set counter = counter + v_counter;
            
                select counter;
        
                    IF counter = 10000 THEN
                        COMMIT;
                        set counter = 0;
                    END IF;
                
                set rowsdeleted = rowsdeleted + counter;
        
                select rowsdeleted;
            
                set recordsProcessed = rowsdeleted;
        
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE Sel_cur;

    END;

COMMIT;

END;
```

DO we have any other way to achieve this with out using Create view?

Thanks

Comment: You use to create dynamic SQL using `PREPARE`.

Comment: No, there is no way at the moment to dynamically provide a table name to a cursor other than creating a view. Why? Because you need dynamic sql to pass table or column name dynamically to an sql statement, but declare cursor statement has to come before any prepare statement and cannot use a string as sql statement.

Comment: Because we don't have an access to create view or table